# Cannot save a custom meta field in quick edit

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have enabled woocommerce and I have several products. I added two columns one textbox one dropdown in quick edit. I can display my data in both fields inside quick edit.

In case of adding or changing one of them or both of them nothing is saved. I used the following:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_fields_from_quickedit', 10, 2 );

function save_fields_from_quickedit( $post_id, $post ) {
// pointless if $_POST is empty (this happens on bulk edit)
if ( empty( $_POST ) )
    return $post_id;

// verify quick edit nonce
if ( isset( $_POST[ '_inline_edit' ] ) && ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ '_inline_edit' ], 'inlineeditnonce' ) )
    return $post_id;

// don't save for autosave
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return $post_id;

// dont save for revisions
if ( isset( $post->post_type ) && $post->post_type == 'revision' )
    return $post_id;

switch( $post->post_type ) {

    case 'product':


        $custom_fields = array( 'test_column', 'test_column2');

        foreach( $custom_fields as $field ) {

            if ( array_key_exists( $field, $_POST ) )
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $field, $_POST[ $field ] );

        }

        break;

}
```

}
but is not working

I tried changing the slug name instead of test_column, I put the id of the column as well and still not working. What I am missing here?

Comment: Does the function get run?  First line inside the function put something like `die('got here');` to make sure it gets fired.  If that does, move it further down, like after each conditional statement.

Comment: Have you checjed the column name and slugs to be appropriate?